# How to claim rent on my taxes

Tags: taxes

can I claim that I pay rent, to a friend who I live with.  Nothing in writing, but I do pay monthly rent and split the utilities.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. For any question tagger 'taxes', we need a country. In many cases, we need a locality. For example in the US, a State.

Comment: What do you mean claim? Are you expecting a deduction or something? Why?

Comment: Which taxes were you referring to - state income tax? Federal income tax? Something else entirely?

Comment: In any jurisdiction the tax office are going to want to see some documentation stating that you have paid the rent. Get your friend to give you a receipt each time you pay.

Answer (score 2):

### US answer

Rent can only be claimed when it is a **valid business expense**.  Otherwise, *every renter* would claim it on their taxes...

(And there are strict rules about what is and isn't valid.  If you try this, even for valid reasons, expect your tax return to be "red flagged" for possibly higher scrutiny.)

Comment: Some states do allow residents to deduct (at least a portion of) rent for their primary residence. Whether that is applicable to this question depends on whether OP is in the US, and if so, which state.

Comment: @yoozer8 for what purpose?  (I know you can deduct "dedicate office space" from federal taxes, but the rules are pretty strict.)

Comment: Some states allow you to deduct rent paid for your primary residence from your taxable income. We have no idea which state OP is filing in (or if even in US at all), so I'm not going to spend any time to dig through all states to come up with a list of which ones allow it and under which circumstances.

Comment: @RonJohn As an example in Indiana you can deduct up to $3000 in paid rent for your primary residence. Unlike the federal home office deduction this one is quite easy to qualify for. You need to have paid rent for a property for which property tax is paid and it must be your primary residence.

Comment: California treats it as a credit, not a deduction: https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/personal/credits/nonrefundable-renters-credit.html  But we need to be clear that these decuctions or credits only apply to state income taxes, not federal.  (And of course if the OP's not in the US, all bets are off.)

Comment: And you are leaving your friend up to explaining why they are not declaring the rental income they are receiving...